# Use of setter in dealloc in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Any problems with the following codes?

```
- (void) dealloc {
    self.foo = nil;
}
```

Instead of

```
- (void) dealloc {
   [_foo release];
   _foo = nil;
}
```

Comment: One note… if you're not using ARC, you need to call `[super dealloc]`, and if you are then you shouldn't call `release`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons not to do the former:

1. If a subclass has overridden the setter, the release might not actually happen.
2. Using the setter might trigger a KVO notification and the observer will receive a notification from an object that technically doesn't exist.

On the other hand, if you use ARC, you don't need to do any of that.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is discouraged against is that it could cause problems. A setter or getter may have side effects

Take this example of a memory leak.

```
- (void)dealloc;
{
    self.iWillLeak = nil;
    self.iCauseTheLeak = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)setICauseTheLeak:(NSArray *)iCauseTheLeak;
{
    if (_iCauseTheLeak != iCauseTheLeak) {
        [_iCauseTheLeak release];
        _iCauseTheLeak = [iCauseTheLeak retain];
    }
    self.iWillLeak = [NSArray array]; // This was already cleared in dealloc
}
```

This is a simple case and there is potential for much more damaging things to occur.

The main takeaway here is that the two are not equivalent as they do different things.

Comment: Note that the same problems can happen if you call `release` directly and something what should be called is not called. It depends on how you write the setters. In your example your setter is not well designed.

Comment: The setter is deliberately written like that to show an example of why it is discouraged to use setters/getters in dealloc.

Comment: What you have shown is only that you should not call setters directly when they are not written correctly.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. It is a contrived example to show that setters can have unwanted side effects, it is not an example of good programming. Your example is a great case for showing that a setter can have hidden side effects that the average developer won't consider e.g. `[...addObserver:nil]` this will most likely cause a crash if the receiver cannot accept `nil`  but the user will not understand why they are crashing when all they are doing is setting something.

Comment: Yes, my examples aren't better than yours. The difference is that you are using this example as a proof that calling setter from dealloc is wrong (or discouraged). It's not. Both cases have their pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

no problem if you declared your `foo` property with `retain` or `copy` attributes
but if you did it using  `assign` you should not do `[_foo release];`

You might find this reading useful:
[Objective-C Memory Management for the Lazy](http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/)

Answer (score 1):

I will write two examples:

1/ Using release directly

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [foo_ release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)setFoo:(Foo*)foo {
   if (foo == foo_) {
       return;
   }

   [foo_ removeObserver:self];
   [foo_ release];

   foo_ = [foo retain];
   [foo_ addObserver:self];
}
```

The observer from `foo_` won't be removed, which is probably an error.

2/ Using setter

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.observer = nil;
    self.foo = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)setFoo:(Foo*)foo {
   if (foo == foo_) {
       return;
   }

   [foo_ removeObserver:self.observer];
   [foo_ release];

   foo_ = [foo retain];
   [foo_ addObserver:self.observer];
}
```

As you can see, another error appears here. We are using a `nil` (`self.observer`) somewhere where `nil` is probably not expected.

In general, neither of the two cases will help catch your bugs. In every case a different type of buggy behavior can appear.

My recommendation would be to use the setters to mantain consistency but it's a matter of opinion.
Anyway, if you write your own setters, check if you are initializing and deallocating properties in the correct order. Also note that your setters can be overriden in subclasses.

Apple recommends to use retain/release directly in init and dealloc but in their own code they use setters (e.g. `UITableView` calls `setDelegate` with a `nil` parameter when deallocating).